# Infimum of the integer part

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Denote by $E(x)$ by the integer part of $x$, and let $x$ belong to the set of real positive numbers where $x$ doesn't equal to zero.
Find $$\inf(E(x) +E(1/x)).$$
Firstly I tried plugging numbers for example 2 and it gave me 2, trying $1/2$ gave me 2, there is like a mirror happening here where numbers are split into 2 intervals that would yield the same answer, however between 1 and 2, excluding both numbers we would always get 1 and 1 is really the smallest element and so it is the infimum.

My question is how to prove it, I can not say that on a Real Analysis exam and thank you.

Comment: Try considering what happens when x=1.5

Comment: @shortmanikos for any x belong to (1,2) i would get 1, 1 is the inf(E(x) +E(1/x)) but how can i say it when it goes to Real Analysis, how can i prove it, thats my question

Comment: Your need to find an inf for a set of non-negative integers. You know that 1 belongs in your set. All you need to show is that for all x, E(x) +E(1/x) cannot equal 0.